# Elasticsearch: ClassNotFoundException CloneSnapshotRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I having `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/elasticsearch/action/admin/cluster/snapshots/clone/CloneSnapshotRequest` exception while running the project. I'm using elasticsearch-7.12.1

**Client Class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "io.pratik.elasticsearch.repositories")
public class ElasticsearchClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo("172.30.224.11:9200")
                .build();
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClientConfig': FactoryBean
> threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/elasticsearch/action/admin/cluster/snapshots/clone/CloneSnapshotRequest

Comment: check out the output of the command dependency:analyze-duplicate. you may have 2 versions of the same dependency somewhere

Comment: @tremendous7 No duplicate dependencies found in <dependencies/> or in <dependencyManagement/>

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.4.5 pulls in Elasticsearch 7.9.3. You change the rest-high-level-client dependency to 7.12.1, but all the other Elasticsearch dependencies will be 7.9.3. Especially org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch. And the `CloneSnapshotRequest` did not exist in 7.9.3.

What's the reason to use a different client library version than the one defined by the Spring Boot dependency management?